# Model is not a function error in postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Iam doing basic crud operation in mongodb when i try to insert new post to db i get a message in post man as Test is not a function.

My router function is as follow.

```
router.route('/createtests').post(function (req, res, next) {

    var Test = new Test(req.body);
    postTest(Test, function (data) {

        res.json({'message': 'The test created sucessfully'});

    });

});

var postTest = function(test, cb){

    Test.save(function(err,data){

        cb(data);

    });

};
```

My schema is as follows.

```
var TestSchema = common.Schema({

title                   : String, 
testCreator             : String,
datePosted              : {
                            type: Date,
                            default: Date.now
                            },
totalQuestions          : Number,
totalTime               : Number,
numberOfPeopleTaking    : Number,
dateOfTest              : Date,
marksPerQuestions       : Number,
imageUrl                : String,
testType                : String,

});
var Test = common.conn.model('Test', TestSchema);
console.log(typeof Test);// logging as function
console.log(Test);// logging full model with schema
module.exports = Test;
```

Iam getting a response as follow

```
{
"message": "Test is not a function",
"error": {}
}
```

Comment: is `common` reference to mongoose ?

Comment: yes. it is an object of mongoose. Schema: require('mongoose').Schema, is a property in common.

Comment: Try `var Test = common.model('Test', TestSchema);`  instead of `var Test = common.conn.model('Test', TestSchema);`

Comment: no actually its not wired up that way it will not work..... conn:require(mongoose).createconnection(dburl), so only i wired up this way..... I have done this even requiring the moongoose in the same file even but the same happens

Comment: is there any stackTrace in your terminal? That'd be helpfull. Also there's spelling issue with T and t.

Comment: Console O/P: POST /tests/createtests error 32.946 ms - 47 I have corrected that spelling thing but still i get the same error. Actually nothing runs after the `var Test = new Test(req.body);` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `postTest` , you have `test` with '`t`' and you are saving with '`T`'(`Test.save()`) : uppercase/lowercase typo. this is what is causing your issue.

```
var postTest = function(test, cb){

    test.save(function(err,data){ //see the change here 'test' instead of 'Test' 

        cb(data);

    });

};
```

Also, change `common.conn.model` to `common.model`

```
var Test = common.model('Test', TestSchema);
```

**EDIT**

You are using `Test` as `variable` name and `model` name both. change the var to `test`. It should solve your issue.

```
router.route('/createtests').post(function (req, res, next) {

    var test = new Test(req.body); //See the change here. 'test' instead of 'Test'
    postTest(test, function (data) { //pass 'test'

        res.json({'message': 'The test created sucessfully'});

    });

});
```

Comment: I edited the answer, Change `common.conn.model` to `common.model`. Can you check if thats working?

Comment: Also, please tell how you have defined `common` . And what is the result when you do `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: `req.body` is logging correctly but  see in last file it is logging the type of Test as function. But once the control reaches the `var Test = new Test(req.body);` it is just send a message as Test is not a function and the rest of the lines are not executing at all.

Comment: Please see my edit, this should solve your issue. Please Confirm if its working.

Comment: that is where the mystery lies. learnt that we should not use both variable object and function object with same name.... !...node is not as much smarter as we are..... !Thanks Ravi ji.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code in correct way.

```
const Test = require('../models/Test'); // path
var test = new Test({
    email: req.body.title,
    password: req.body.testType
});

test.save(function(err,data){

    cb(data);

});
```

Comment: Because the way you are doing is wrong. Try to print on console - {req.body} - object you are passing is wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing an instance of "Test" as a parameter but you are using `Test` as instance instead of `test`.

you can try this hope that will work. Since just tested it with dummy record and it works and if it doesn't make sense mean your mongoose schema has issue

```
 router.route('/createtests').post(function (req, res, next) {

        var Test = new Test(req.body);
        postTest(Test, function (data) {

            res.json({'message': 'The test created sucessfully'});
        });
    });

    var postTest = function(test, cb){

        test.save(function(err,data){
            if(!err)
            cb(null,data);
        });
    };
```